# Getting clangd to work in an Android NDK project

Tags: android, c++, emacs, android-ndk, clangd

I'm trying to work on android NDK project using clangd (via emacs/eglot), but I'm not very experienced with C++ and don't really understand the issue I'm having.

I'm working on a project that I created by following [these instructions](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/Android#simple_builds). So in a nutshell, it's [this file](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/test/testgles.c) in an NDK project. I can get intellisense working in VS Code by setting the compiler to the NDK C++ compiler, specifying the right includes, and adding a define for **ANDROID**:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "compilerPath": "/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android32-clang++",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/",
                "/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/GLES/**",
                "/Users/zebra/development/cpp/SDL2-2.28.4/build/org.libsdl.testgles/app/jni/SDL2_image-2.6.3"
            ],
            "defines": ["__ANDROID__"],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

I tried to recreate this setup with a .clangd file:

```
CompileFlags:
    Add: [
      "-std=c++17",
      "-I/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/",
      "-I/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/GLES/",
      "-I/Users/zebra/development/cpp/SDL2-2.28.4/include",
      "-I/Users/zebra/development/cpp/SDL2-2.28.4/build/org.libsdl.testgles/app/jni/SDL2_image-2.6.3",
      "-D__ANDROID__",
      ]
    Compiler: "/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android32-clang++"
```

but I'm getting a ton of LSP errors for missing asm includes. I used to get these in VS Code, but I got rid of them by setting the compiler to the NDK compiler. For example, this is an error clangd is currently giving me:

```
"In included file: 'asm/types.h' file not found
/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/linux/types.h:21:10:
note: error occurred here
```

The debug output for eglot shows that it's using the ndk compiler, so I'm not sure why I'm having this issue or how to fix it.

```
[stderr] /Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android32-clang++
-std=c++17
-I/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/
-I/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include/GLES/
-I/Users/zebra/development/cpp/SDL2-2.28.4/include
-I/Users/zebra/development/cpp/SDL2-2.28.4/build/org.libsdl.testgles/app/jni/SDL2_image-2.6.3
-D__ANDROID__
-resource-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/14.0.3
-- /Users/zebra/development/cpp/SDL2-2.28.4/build/org.libsdl.testgles/app/jni/src/testgles.cpp
```

In other projects, I would use `bear` to intercept compilation and "just work". But in this project, that doesn't seem to be an option, because gradle is building an apk, and bear doesn't seem to be able to intercept the C compilation that takes place. Does anyone know what I can do to make clangd work correctly on this file?

Answer (score 1):

The fix for issues like this is generally to use [--query-driver](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc):

> If you’re using an unusual compiler (e.g. **a cross-compiler for a different platform**) you may want to pass `--query-driver=/path/to/mygcc` or `--query-driver=/path/to/mygcc,/path/to/myg++` when using C++ to allow clangd to extract the include paths from it directly.

More details on `--query-driver` can be found [here](https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers#query-driver).

So, in your case, you'd add `--query-driver=/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android32-clang++` (matching the `Compiler` in `.clangd`) to the clangd command line arguments in your emacs lsp configuration.

Comment: Hum, I did manage to add --query-driver:

`[stderr] I[06:10:38.662] argv[0]: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clangd`

`[stderr] I[06:10:38.662] argv[1]: --query-driver=/Users/zebra/Library/Android/ndk/26.0.10792818/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android32-clang++`

but the error still remains:

`In included file: 'asm/types.h' file not found`

Comment: @UnsatisfiedZebra could you share full [clangd logs](https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#gathering-logs) please?

Comment: sorry the formatting is a nightmare, the asm/types.h error is the only one that shouldn't be there. https://pastes.io/moterfo4gj

Comment: @UnsatisfiedZebra I believe you're running into https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/1089. You need to either use clangd 16 or later, or generate a `compile_commands.json` file for the project (see https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup). The latter is probably a good idea to do anyways, as it's often needed for project-specific configuration (e.g. project-specific include paths).

Comment: that was what I was afraid of, since the project is built via gradle, which `bear` cannot seem to hook in to to generate compile_commands.json. There are efforts to add CMake support to the repository (SDL2) which generated this project, but they are incomplete at the now. What's crazy to me is that I have no idea how VS Code is able to make this "just work" through the configuration I provided, I was presuming it was just a thin layer over clangd but it must be much more elaborate.

Comment: @UnsatisfiedZebra Have a look at https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r18#changes: "ndk-build can now generate a JSON Compilation Database." (SDL's `androidbuild.sh` script seems to be a wrapper for `ndk-build`, so presumably it has a way to pass flags to `ndk-build`)